# Julia cannot be launched in Juno IDE

Tags: julia, juno-ide

I'm trying to launch Julia in the Juno IDE but it returns

```
  We tried to launch Julia from:
     julia
  This path can be changed in the settings.
  Details:
  /bin/sh: julia: command not found
```

Ive searched around the forums, tried setting the julia path to

```
C:\Julia-1.0.3\bin
```

and reinstalling the julia-client packages, but nothing seems to work. Julia is able to start through command line.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using windows? Is that the actual file path on your computer to Julia or just found that snippet of code online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Juno plugin is sometimes not stable. Reinstall it. The steps below will work for Windows:

1. Make sure that typing `julia` in the console actually starts Julia - this can be achieved by adding to your `PATH` variable the `julia` executable location (for example `c:\Julia-1.0.3\bin` - in Windows 10 go to the "Advanced System Settings" and select "Environment variables" to edit the `PATH` settings)
2. Stop Atom
3. Delete `%USERPROFILE%\.atom` folder (the actual path looks something like `C:\Users\YOUR-NAME\.atom`)
4. Start Atom, press `Ctrl`+`,` for the package manager and install Juno